# JHipster programatically login using cypress and JWT

Tags: typescript, jhipster, cypress

How can I bypass JHipster login screen programatically?

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
let jwt_token

before(function fetchUser() {
    cy.request('POST', '/api/authenticate', {
        username: 'user',
        password: 'user',
    })
        .its('body')
        .then((res) => {
            jwt_token = res.id_token
        })
})

beforeEach(function setUser() {
    cy.visit('/', {
        onBeforeLoad(win) {
            win.sessionStorage.setItem('jhi-authenticationtoken', jwt_token);
            win.localStorage.setItem('jhi-authenticationtoken', jwt_token);
        }
    })
})

describe('test', () => {
    it('check login works programmatically', () => {
        cy.log(jwt_token);
        cy.visit('/');
        cy.get('.lead').should('have.text', 'Here is microservices catalog');
        cy.get('#home-logged-message').should('have.text', 'You are logged in as user "user".');
    })
})
```

I can clearly see that jwt_token is filled with correct value. Unfortunately login is still not working and 'test' fails.

Anybody have positive experience with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use quotation marks around token itself. Here is example how you can authenticate when JWT is used in your JHipster application

```
function login(username: string, password: string): void {
  cy.request('POST', '/api/authenticate', {
    username: username,
    password: password
  })
    .its('body')
    .then((res) => {
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('jhi-authenticationtoken', '"' + res.id_token + '"');
    })
}
```

You can find live example [here](https://github.com/tillias/microservice-catalog/blob/master/cypress/support/commands.ts)

Comment: My application uses Local Storage for JWT tokens so in my case it was `window.localStorage.setItem` but your answer probably saved me a few hours, thank you!